# Dynamic template for single custom post

Tags: custom-post-types

I am trying to create a dynamic template for all custom post types I create.
I understand I can put the post type slug in "Template Post Type:" in the header comments of my template but how can I populate this dynamically?

eg. this is how I would like my header comments to work but I obviosuly can't use a variable in the comments .

```
<?php
$custom_post_types = 'post, page, my_custom_post_type1, my_custom_post_type2';

/**
 Template name: Home
 Template Post Type:  $custom_post_types 
*/
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic template"?

Comment: a template that can be used for any custom post type that is created.